# Interference of ARUs with Electric Fencing

Tags: audiomoth

I am currently planning a deployment of some-hundred Audiomoths for an acoustic survey project.

Since my project is partly located on meadows, I'll have to use some already existing structures to install the ARUs. I'll place the AudioMoths at fences, which will have peak currents of 7kV. So more or less regular electrical fencing.

Do you have any experience with interference or problems with AudioMoths installed very close or at electrical fences?

Exited to hear of your experiences!

Best,

Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [this link](https://www.radioandtvhelp.co.uk/questions/everything-else/can-an-electric-fence-cause-interference#:%7E:text=Can%20an%20electric%20fence%20cause%20interference%3F%20Electric%20fences,not%20cause%20interference%20to%20television%20or%20radio%20reception.)

> Electric fences operate by sending a pulse of high-voltage electricity around an open-wire metal fence. In normal operation,
> where the system is properly earthed, an electric fence should not
> cause interference to television or radio reception.
>
> When an electric fence is not working properly, the electrical pulses
> from it can sometimes cause interference to Freeview reception and to
> the radio, particularly DAB and AM, if the fence is close to your
> property.

while this relates to radio/TV it may also be an indication if electronic devices may be interfered with.

My suggestion is: if you hear disturbance on your radio, you could suspect possible interferences on your recorder.

What to do about this: I would try to wrap the recorder (with hole for microphone) into alu foil that is connected to ground.

Comment: Great, that's what I was sort of looking for. I'll try the "earthing" but it will be only on few sites for testing prbably..

Comment: Make sure the aluminum foil Faraday is well grounded. In the past I've run into difficulty when my ground rod was inadequate or I failed to make a proper electrical connection to the ground rod. An inadequate ground can be worse then no ground at all since a poorly grounded ground wire can act as an antenna.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know specifically about electric fences but when placing recorders (SM4 - wildlife acoustics) near high-voltage powerlines, I had to discard most of the recordings due to a strong continuous electric buzzing sound (discharge) and short metallic "clicks". Wet grass or insects touching the fence can create "zapping" sounds.

If electricity-borne noise pollution is part of your interest it makes sense to record it - it is there (but also then - recording it only by the source doesn't properly represent its presence at the habitat scale). Yet, it is a different story if this disturbs you from finding focal wildlife vocalizations.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks for your insights. Unfortunately, it turns out the only really available place to put my AudioMoths is more or less at the fence. So Im Hoping the majority of fences will not do the "clicking thing". On the other hand, I want to look into acoustic niches, so if there's some anthropogenic sound as the fence buzzing, its not too much of a bummer.